# CSS select the first element that doesn't have a class

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a couple of `<div>`s, and some of them have `class: hidden`, like this:

```
<div id="firstDiv" class="hidden">content</div>
<div id="secondDiv">content</div>
```

I know want to select the first `<div>` that has NOT the `class: hidden`.
I was trying this so far in `CSS`: `div:not(.hidden):first-child` but it's not working.

How do I write the selectors correctly?

Comment: your current selector will catch the elements that don't have the `.hidden` class, **and** are first child of some element.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/SS9dm/)

**html**

```
<div id="firstDiv" class="hidden">content</div>
<div id="secondDiv">content</div> <!-- only this one will be selected -->
<div id="thirdDiv">content</div>
```

**css**

```
div:not(.hidden)
{
    background-color: red;
}
div:not(.hidden) ~ div:not(.hidden)
{
    background-color: white; /*reset everything to normal*/
}
```

Comment: +1 Nice Answer, Although it's not yet fully cross compatible I would believe?

Comment: why not? it's a [valid selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors).

Comment: But don't worry, I am still upvoting =)!

Comment: the OP also had a `:not` selector in his question.. so no problem here. & thanks for the UV

Comment: Haha true! I had totally missed that t_t Apologies.

Comment: But does the [`Extended arguments - Not supported`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not#Browser_compatibility) answer the initial question mind you? :o for `div:not(.hidden):first-child`

Comment: @avrahamcool although the fiddle works perfectly and is doing what I want, it wont work on my code... I'm trying to find if there's an issue in it.

Comment: @lucaber can you post your full code with the problem in a fiddle?

Comment: @avrahamcool the problem is, that i don't know where it is :/ when I put all relevant things in a fiddle it is working perfectly http://jsfiddle.net/X2LDB/1/

Comment: @avrahamcool I am sorry the whole code is way too complex to post it here or make a fiddle. And when I extract the code it's not more than the fiddle above. Anyway, thanks for your help and since your answer helped and actually is the code I was looking for I'll mark is right. I'll ask co-workers of mine if they have any ideas. When I found out what was wrong I'll comment it here.

Comment: @avrahamcool I am so so dumb. Even to dumb to simply copy&paste. I just had a misspelling. I guess I need a break right now ;_;

Answer (score 0):

using the next sibling selector `+` you could write something that will always find the first div that is not hidden, after a hidden div.

```
div.hidden + div:not(.hidden) 
{
    background-color: #ff0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mbFFQ/

Comment: and if the not hidden is the first in the parent?